# Random characters in DS record from Net::DNS:RR when calling print/string

Tags: perl, dns

The `Net::DNS` version is 1.22.

---

I'm playing around with [Net::DNS::RR](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::DNS::RR) and I am a bit confused about some random characters appearing in the output of DS records when I call `Net::DNS::RR->string`(or `Net::DNS::RR->print`). The output for `Net::DNS::RR->plain` is what I expected.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings; 

use Net::DNS; 

my @rr = rr("gov.uk", "DS");
print STDERR $_->plain . "\n" foreach (@rr);
print STDERR $_->string . "\n" foreach (@rr);
```

The output is as follows:

```
gov.uk. 300 IN DS 17539 8 2 2f0a0a65db9e930f5b2c0425f67df66416c076124652a281d9a8ffa773828f57
gov.uk. 300 IN DS 695 8 2 7277592dbd8993bde70704dbabd30afdbb85057e658ef1428f18f5d9a534bce0
gov.uk. 300     IN      DS      ( 17539 8 2
        2f0a0a65db9e930f5b2c0425f67df66416c076124652a281d9a8ffa773828f57 )
        ; xerob-pidyk-hukan-vagab-zokod-seced-hetal-tutok-gohys-bityc-ducih-demom-cekup-mazip-lasem-difoh-lixex
gov.uk. 300     IN      DS      ( 695 8 2
        7277592dbd8993bde70704dbabd30afdbb85057e658ef1428f18f5d9a534bce0 )
        ; xisil-lykud-tazum-nagar-tynib-licot-repat-fydoz-tivam-hicul-vunim-vosag-dofic-metyt-nunuf-gezev-byxex
```

As one can see, the `plain` response is as expected, meanwhile the `string` output has a bunch of seemingly random characters after the record (`xerob-pidyk-huk...`).

Can anyone shed light on what's happening here?

Comment: edited, it's 1.22

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get those comments if [Digest::BubbleBabble](https://metacpan.org/pod/Digest::BubbleBabble) is installed.

It's an alternate representation of the digest in the record.

`hex_to_babble`:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use v5.36;
use Digest::BubbleBabble qw( bubblebabble );
die( "usage" ) if @ARGV != 1 || $ARGV[0] !~ /^(?:[0-9a-fA-F]{2})*\z/;
say bubblebabble( Digest => pack( "H*", $ARGV[0] ) );
```

```
$ hex_to_babble 2f0a0a65db9e930f5b2c0425f67df66416c076124652a281d9a8ffa773828f57
xerob-pidyk-hukan-vagab-zokod-seced-hetal-tutok-gohys-bityc-ducih-demom-cekup-mazip-lasem-difoh-lixex

$ hex_to_babble 7277592dbd8993bde70704dbabd30afdbb85057e658ef1428f18f5d9a534bce0
xisil-lykud-tazum-nagar-tynib-licot-repat-fydoz-tivam-hicul-vunim-vosag-dofic-metyt-nunuf-gezev-byxex
```

The point is to make it easier for humans to transcribe the digest or compare two digests.